# Хочу начать изучать Javascript

Tags: javascript, книги

Какие книжки посоветуете? Какие советы дадите? С чего предлагаете начать?

Comment: [поиск по сайту][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/181589/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-javascript-html5-node-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Купи или скачай книгу Дэвида Флэнегана "Javascript Подробное руководство **6 издание** ".
Практика ждёт тебя на http://learn.javascript.ru.

Answer (score 0):

Шаг за шагом, где есть лекции с контрольными интерактивными заданиями, дающими возможность проанализировать насколько усвоен материал. [Здесь](http://www.intuit.ru/department/internet/js/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно попробовать Code Academy: http://www.codecademy.com/ru/tracks/javascript

Comment: codeacademy банальный и скучный. нет смысла его продвигать.

Comment: и все же, новичкам в самый раз

Comment: если отпугнуть только.